# SEVERE: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

Hi am facing below error using spring project and with oracle ojdbc14-1.4.jar
java version 1.8 and tomcat 7.0.37

When i execute the SQL directly in oracle its working fine not sure what I am missing in spring JDBC.

Also I had tried other oracle driver versions from maven

inside spring configuration file

```
    <bean id="dataSourceDB" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" 
         destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url_revdbo}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
         <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> 
        <property name="initialSize" value="${database.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${database.maxActive}" />
    <property name="minIdle" value="${database.minIdle}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${database.maxIdle}" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="${database.maxWait}" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${database.testWhileIdle}" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${database.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database.validationQuery}" />
</bean>


<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplateDB"" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSourceDB" />
</bean>
```

inside java DAO layer

```
        private String INSERT_REVENUE_DATA= "INSERT INTO table_test (BATCH_ID,status) values ( '1234','new')";


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("namedParameterJdbcTemplateDB")
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplateDB;

        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<>();
        //paramMap.put("field1", "1111");
        //paramMap.put("field2", "new");

        namedParameterJdbcTemplateRevport.update(INSERT_DATA, paramMap);


oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver registerMBeans
SEVERE: Error while registering Oracle JDBC Diagnosability MBean.
    javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character '\n' in value part of property
    at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:618)
    at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(ObjectName.java:1382)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:303)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:213)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:209)
```

Comment: can you share your code please?

Comment: You're going to need to provide quite a lot more information about what you're doing that's leading to this exception. The message seems to be saying that there is a newline character somewhere that it's not expected, but nobody's going to be able to tell you where without some context. I suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to include the suggestions from there.

Comment: *Invalid character '\n' in value part of property*

Comment: @YCF_L  added more info in post

Answer (score 0):

You get this error :

```
javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: 
Invalid character '\n' in value part of property
```

because you have two quotes in the property :

```
<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplateDB""
//------------------------------------^^
```

You have to use just one